# Getting error in using exsiting code for ant colony optimization in python got error dytpe datum not found

Tags: python, numpy, ant-colony

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user54\Desktop\AntColonyOptimizationGist.py", line 230, in <module>
    optimize(500, 500, 250, 500000, 25, 10, freq=500, path="Video 8/")
  File "C:\Users\user54\Desktop\AntColonyOptimizationGist.py", line 214, in optimize
    grid = Grid(height, width, path)
  File "C:\Users\user54\Desktop\AntColonyOptimizationGist.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.grid = numpy.empty((height, width), dtype=Datum)
TypeError: data type not understood
```

The code I get from internet is:

```
class AntColonyOptimization:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Grid:
    def __init__(self, height, width, path, rand_test=True):
        """
        This method initializes a grid object. A grid is basically just a 2D array of Datum objects
        :param height: this is the height of the grid
        :param width: this is the weight of the grid
        """
        self.path = path
        # Store the dimensions of the grid
        self.dim = numpy.array([height, width])
        # Initialize an empty numpy matrix of type Datum

        self.grid = numpy.empty((height, width), dtype=Datum)
        if rand_test:
            # This is used to fill the grid randomly
            self.rand_grid(0.25)
        # This makes the plot redraw
        plt.ion()
        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
        self.max_d = 0.001

    def rand_grid(self, sparse):
        """
        A method for randomly initializing the grid
        :param sparse: the percentage of the grid to fill up
        """
        for y in range(self.dim[0]):
            for x in range(self.dim[1]):
                if random.random() <= sparse:
                    r = random.randint(0, 1)
                    if r == 0:
                        self.grid[y][x] = Datum(nrand.normal(5, 0.25, 10))
                    elif r == 1:
                        self.grid[y][x] = Datum(nrand.normal(-5, 0.25, 10))   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    optimize(500, 500, 250, 500000, 25, 10, freq=500, path="Video 8/")
```

Can any one give me a solution?

Comment: Is `Datum` the name of your class? If so, then you must use `dtype=object` instead.

Comment: datum is supposed to be a datatype i am using python 2.7 for this work so i was unable to get packages such as caffe to use datum class.

Comment: datum class hasclass Datum:
    def __init__(self, data):
        """
        A Datum object is basically just a ND vector
        :param data: the ND vector
        """
        self.data = data

Comment: after creating object still getting error

Comment: full code is at the link https://gist.github.com/StuartGordonReid/09abf6a7dc9cfaf85506#file-antcolonyoptimizationgist-py

Comment: If you want to use this class, then you have to `import caffe`

Comment: but caffe require more dependencies i tried my best to install caffee but i couldnt

Comment: If you want to use it, then you have to install it. There is no way of using the package without installing it first.

Comment: how to install caffe for windows and pyton 2.7 with numpy 1.10

Comment: i thank everyone for their help on time